# Word2Vec model output types

Tags: word2vec, gensim

When Word2Vec model is trained, there are three outputs created.

- model
- model.wv.syn0
- model.syn1neg

I have a couple of questions regarding these models.

1. How are these outputs essentially different from each other?
2. Which model to look at if I want to access trained results?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Those are 3 files created by the gensim `Word2Vec` `.save()` function. The `model` file is a Python pickle of the main model; the other files are some of the over-large numpy arrays stored separately for efficiency. The `syn0` happens to contain the raw word vectors, and the `syn1neg` the model's internal weights – but neither are cleanly interpretable without the other data.

So, the only support for re-loading them is to use the matching `.load()` function, with all three available. A successful re-`load()` will result in a model object just like the one you `save()`d, and you'd access the results via that loaded object.

(If you *only* need the raw word-vectors, you can also use the `.save_word2vec_format()` method, which writes in a format compatible with the original Google-releases `word2vec.c` code. But that format has strictly less information that `gensim`'s native save, so you'd only use it if you absolutely need to for compatibility with other software. Working with the `gensim` native files ensures you could always save the other format later, while you can't go the other way.)